# The use of "was" in a question

Tags: questions, subjunctives

So, I'm currently working on something and simply cannot get my head around one specific question. Apart from the fact that I could easily paraphrase the question, I was wondering if the use of "was" or "is" was correct here, and, more interestingly, why.

"Why would it be naive to think that Standard-English **was/is** the best way of speaking English?"

I feel as if there's only a slight nuance between "is" and "was", the latter putting an emphasis on the fact that thinking SE is (or *was*? :P) the best way of speaking English, **is/was**, in fact, naive; however, wouldn't that lead to some sort of redundancy since the first part of the question already suggests exactly that?

Any ideas? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

To ask why it *was* naive is to indicate that you are asking about a past situation.  For instance, why an Englishman on the Grand Tour would think that.

To ask why it *is* is to indicate you are asking about the current situation.

If, indeed, you wanted to ask why it was in the past and still is now, you would have to use both.